# Syntax error when working on OCaml/LLVM tutorial

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, llvm

I am reading the tutorial of implementing kaleidoscope language on LLVM using ocaml. However, the given code lexer.ml doesn't compile...

There is a syntax error in the second line of the code

```
let rec lex = parser
   (* Skip any whitespace. *)
   | [< ' (' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\t'); stream >] -> lex stream
```

Why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the code on its own or are you using the full code from the code listing in chapter 2 (including the `_tags` file)? And which command are you using to compile?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old stream syntax, provided by camlp4. See the [tutorial](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/tutorial-camlp4/tutorial002.html). Enabling the syntax support highly depends on your build system. Please, provide more information on that, and I will update the posting.